# Simple Spring and Maven Application - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, exception, osx-mavericks

Because I have some weird issues with my Maven application, I have decided to create the most simple Spring standalone Java application managed with Maven to find out where my problem is. I'm attaching my all code, the code is the simplest as can be but something is wrong. I must be blind but do you see what could causes this Exception?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

---

My system setting:

```
macbook:Notification jirka$ env
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/tx/c11w5sf11zj6qbfh5skp8kx00000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-jFadXh/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=326
TERM_SESSION_ID=827724B1-6606-411F-B9A4-8649BF09D455
USER=jirka
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-0SCequ/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:29:56
PATH=/Users/jirka/java/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin
__CHECKFIX1436934=1
PWD=/Users/jirka/Documents/workspace/sandbox/Notification
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
LANG=cs_CZ.UTF-8
M2_HOME=/Users/jirka/java/apache-maven-3.1.1
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/jirka
LOGNAME=jirka
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/Users/jirka/Documents/workspace/sandbox
```

what is not set is `CLASS_PATH`, but this is content of `.classpath` file in the root directory of my app - I'm not sure if the missing `CLASS_PATH` is not the problem. If so, where should `CLASS_PATH` points to on OS X and Maven 3?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

---

I created Maven project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=Sandbox -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I set dependencies into `pom.xml` configuration file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>Sandbox</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Notification</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Then I created simple Spring app...

Content of `applicationContext.xml` file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="helloBean" class="com.example.HelloWorld">
        <property name="name" value="Jirka" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and `HelloWorld.java`:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello ! " + name);
    }
}
```

and App.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "applicationContext.xml");
        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloBean");
        obj.printHello();
    }
}
```

Then I packaged app into jar file:

```
mvn package
```

and tryied to run it:

```
java -cp target/Notification-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.App
```

but this errors occured:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Please read this [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your Maven setup lets you compile your code and build the jar, but Spring isn't in the runtime classpath. Add Spring to `-cp` at the command line.

Or use the Maven assembly plugin to build an "uber" jar containing your code and all the dependencies, and run that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I mentioned Spring jar in dependencies in pom.xml. I have to download Spring jar at add the jar as value into `-cp` parameter again?

Comment: You just need to distinguish between the compile classpath and the runtime classpath. What you did in Maven is compile and build with a sufficient compile classpath. You are running from the command line with an insufficient *runtime* classpath. Building the uber jar would fix that. If you were building a war file, you would also be fine because Spring would automatically be packaged in the war file, where `WEB-INF/lib` is in the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a small java project , i have used Spring and using eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1). All I did is right click on the project->export->runnable jar file . select the radio button copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated jar and click on finish.
Then go to the command prompt select the location where the Jar was created and give the following 
command `java -jar jarname`
This should work .